# Are there unicode overlap characters?

Tags: unicode

Are there any Unicode characters that essentially are non-overwriting backspaces?

I have  and I would like them to overlap.

Comment: What do you mean overlap? And I cannot see very well the symbols in my system (very recent macos). You write overwriting, but then overlapping. But probably you means combining characters? In any case Unicode code just music symbols (for text) With ZWJ you may join characters (if font support it). Probably you should go to a higher protocol to write music).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no such Unicode character.

In the days long gone, this used to be the functionality of the control code U+0008 BACKSPACE, but the Unicode Standard ascribes no further semantics to that character beyond “It’s that old ASCII control code”, and you would be hard-pressed to find any modern application that supports this archaic behaviour.