# Using REPT() with Decimals

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was wondering about being able to use/make a function like REPT() to display partial repetitions with decimal numbers. My formula, as it stands, works fine for integers. If I wanted to give 3 stars, I just use `=REPT(CHAR(9733), 3)` and that prints 3 black stars.

Let's say I wanted to give something 4.2 stars. Is there a way to do something like this? I've been trying to figure out a way to do it with App Script, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Everything I've researched online is geared towards making a clickable rating system with HTML/CSS/JavaScript. But I'd be looking more for something like an average rating on Amazon or something.

This is what I have with App Script so far:

```
function starRating() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('test');
  var cell = sheet.getRange(2,1); // Sets a test cell
  
  // Create a concatenated string of 5 blank stars
  var blankStars = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    blankStars = blankStars.concat(String.fromCharCode(9734));
  }

  // Create a concatenated string of 5 black stars
  var blackStars = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    blackStars = blackStars.concat(String.fromCharCode(9733));
  }

  cell.setValue(blankStars);
  cell.setHorizontalAlignment("center")
  cell.setFontSize(18);

  var rating = sheet.getRange(1,1).getValue(); // Raw Rating (e.g. 4.3)
  var amount = Math.max(0, (Math.min(5, rating))) * 20; // Gets percent out of 100, also ensures rating is from 0-5

  /*
  Maybe find a way to overlay the blackStar on top of blankStar?
    Use amount as a way of only showing percent of blackStar?
  */
}
```

As I put in the comment, my thought was to overlay a percent of the blackStar string on top of the blankStar string, but 1. I don't know how to do that and 2. I don't know how that could be put into the cell.

Comment: Maybe `=sparkline()` would be easier?

Comment: I know there's a lot of cool things to do with sparkline (I've seen a working analog clock using it and a lot of cosine and sine functions), but I'm not sure how I would be able to get it to do what I want. I don't really like the look of a simple bar chart for this application

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65369785/are-there-unicode-overlap-characters

Answer (score -1):

This is fairly close and a lot easier

```
function stars(n = 9) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const style = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setForegroundColor("#000000").setFontSize(16).build();
  let s = "";
  Array.from(new Array(10).keys()).forEach(x => s = s.concat(String.fromCharCode(x < n ? 9733 : 9734)));
  sh.getRange(3, 1).setValue(s).setTextStyle(style);
}
```

[image]